# Why is UIkIt 3 source not viewable?

Tags: css, html, firefox, web

If you right click to view source for this website https://getuikit.com/docs/introduction why is is that you can not see the actual code using Firefox?

Comment: Because it builds the page with JavaScript. Use the element inspector (right click -> "Inspect Element") to view the generated HTML.

Comment: In inspector how do you copy the whole source?

Comment: Right click on the <html> element and select Edit as HTML. You can then copy the source